# Why does cordova change my plugin .java class to something broken?

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins

I'm using the micVolume plugin (which wasn't totally working so I adapted it). I can get it mostly working - it reads the microphone volume but the stop(), read() and start() functions can become broken if for example stop() is called twice in a row. For that reason I edited the java class to this:

```
private void stop(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
  if (micOn = true) {
   audioRecord.stop();
   audioRecord.release();
   audioRecord = null;
  micOn = false;
  }

callbackContext.success();
}
```

I should note that micOn is defined earlier on. But this doesn't make any difference to how the app runs on my phone. I decided to decompile the apk and look at the java class, it's been changed to this:

```
   private void stop(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    CallbackContext callbackContext2 = callbackContext;
    MicVolumePlugin micVolumePlugin = this;
    boolean z = true;
    boolean z2 = z;
    r5.micOn = z;
    if (z2) {
        this.audioRecord.stop();
        this.audioRecord.release();
        this.audioRecord = null;
        this.micOn = false;
    }
    callbackContext2.success();
}
```

As you can see, z2 is always going to equate to true and this is not what I want. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you build cordova app through command line it will alter some files, but if you do it from Android studio it will not.

Reason is because whatever the files are there in www folder is copied directly to platform when you built from command line, but in Android studio we have to do it manually.

so check in any other place you have done wrong like z2 = z ? (Other than your corrent plugin.java )

Comment: I'm confused, are you suggesting I use Android Studio to build my cordova app? Is that possible?
Are you saying I'll have z2 = z in one of my other classes that is causing this to happen?

Comment: No am not suggesting you to use Android studio, Just said difference! Just check is there any z2=z in one of your other classes.

Comment: Got round the problem by implementing checks to see if the mic is activated using the javascript instead of within the java plugin class. Not ideal but does the job fine.